# .htaccess redirect with GET parameters and URL condition

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

I try to redirect to another domain and changing the URL structure (not keeping URI part) based on 2 conditions:

1. The original URL has "lang" parameter.
2. The original URI begins with "page".

It's Apache 2.2

This is working when only have the lang paramenter in the orginal URL:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en$
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.destination.com/en/? [R=301,L]
```

For example it redirects ok for:

```
http://www.origin.com/?lang=en
```

to:

```
http://www.destination.com/en/
```

But I also need to redirect something like:

```
http://www.origin.com/page/5/?lang=en
```

to:

```
http://www.destination.com/en/
```

I'm trying things like this, but doesn't work, I think there's something wrong in the `RewriteRule` pattern:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^lang=en$
RewriteRule ^/page/.*/?$ https://www.destination.com/en/? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

You may not want to do have a `?` at the end of your RewriteRule. However, if you wish to have you can do so. Maybe, you want to have a RewriteRule similar to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} lang=en$
    RewriteRule (.*)(\?lang=en) https://www.destination.com/en/ [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

- You might want to restart your apache, with a command similar to:

  ```
    sudo apachectl restart
  ```
- You might clear your browser cache every time that you make a change on `.htaccess` file

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how your expression works, if you wish to know:

[image]

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/jaoSsO/1) can help you to simply design any rule that you like to have.

I have assumed that you want to redirect all your `?lang=en` containing ULRs to a single URL. I was not sure about that. If that's not the case, you may not use my expression.

Comment: Thank you Emma.
The tool is fantastic to test expressions, I bookmarked it.
Anyway, I don't know why, the RewriteRule is not working (it does not affect the behaviour when I browse to a suposed matching URL).

The ? at the end is just to avoid the parameters in the destination URL (I don't want it in destination).

My first example works, as explained, when the source URL is like `http://www.origin.com/?lang=en`, and I don't know why it does not when I try the rewrite rule like yours.

Also yes, I use new "incognito browser" each time I try (the apache restart looks innecessary).

Comment: No, it does not introduce any change, looks like apache passthrought this rules doing nothing. Does it work on your apache?